# Store and Get Application's Shared Preferences In Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin, sharedpreferences

I want to save `sharedpreferences`in `MainActivity`, and get it from `MenusActivity`
I tried this:

`MainActivity`:

```
ISharedPreferences _prefs;
ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = _prefs.Edit();
editor.PutString("User", type);
editor.Apply();
```

`MenusActivity`:

```
ISharedPreferences _prefs=Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("User", FileCreationMode.Private);
```

I think I'm not storing `sharedpreferences` in `MainActivity` on application level.

So, any ideas how to store `sharedpreferences` globally?

Comment: what is ISharedPreferences? A class of Your own or is it a third lib?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs `Interface for accessing and modifying preference data returned by Context.GetSharedPreferences(string, Android.Content.FileCreationMode). For any particular set of preferences, there is a single instance of this class that all clients share. Modifications to the preferences must go through an Android.Content.ISharedPreferencesEditor object to ensure the preference values remain in a consistent state and control when they are committed to storage. Objects that are returned from the various get methods must be treated as immutable by the application.`

Comment: I'm writing in xamarin.android. here's a documentation
http://androidapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=T%3AAndroid.Content.ISharedPreferences

Comment: ah ok...xamarin, have not used until now...

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. already fixed it ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, did it.
changed this:

```
ISharedPreferences _prefs=Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("User", FileCreationMode.Private);
```

to this:

```
ISharedPreferences _prefs=PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(Application.Context);
```